# Limitation of IN function in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have some inquiries related to `IN` function in MySQL. how many variable can store within In function ?

Example:

```
select * from staff where id in ('1','2',......'????')
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

> The number of values in the IN list is only limited by the [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) value.